# Макрос на генерацию функций при помощи _Generic

Tags: c, generics, препроцессор, define

Приветствую откликнувшихся! Столкнулся с задачей, где нужно было написать конверторы из void* простого типа в строку,
Что бы использовать их далее при конвертации сложных структур в строки.
Описал функцию для одного типа так:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void i32_to_str(void* data, char* buffer, size_t buffer_size) {
    if (data && buffer)
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%" PRIi32 " ", *(int32_t*)data);
}
...
```

Данная функция работает и не выдаёт никаких предупреждений. Момент склейки `"%" PRIi32 " "` проходит нормально.

Но, далее, что бы не описывать такую функцию для каждого типа решил попробовать макросы:

```c
#define type_format(T) _Generic((T),\
int16_t: PRIi16,\
int32_t: PRIi32,\
float: "g",\
default: PRIi32)

#define declare(T)\
void T##_to_str(void* data, char* buffer, size_t buffer_size) {\
    if (data && buffer)\
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%" type_format( T ) " ", *( T *)data);\
}

declare(int);
declare(unsigned);
declare(float);
```

Однако тут уже ругается на `"%" type_format( T ) " "` , якобы пропущена `)`.
Почему такое происходит? Как это работает и возможно ли написать макрос по другому, что бы это работало. Спасибо.

U.D.P: Исправил оплошность с вызовом `snprintf()` Спасибо @KoVadim

Comment: *"что бы не описывать такую функцию для каждого типа решил попробовать макросы"* - попробуйте лучше шаблоны в с++.

Comment: @user7860670 , Спасибо за совет, но мне хочется продолжать углубляться в Си.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что `_Generic` делает выбор **по типу выражения** (например, имени переменной), а **не по имени типа данных**.

Решается это дополнительным макросом, который вызывает основной, правильно преобразовав аргумент.

Например, у меня получилось вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "inttypes.h"


#define type__format(T) _Generic((T),\
int16_t: "%" PRIi16 " ",\
int32_t: "%" PRIi32 " ",\
float: "%g ",\
default: "%" PRIi32 " ")

#define type_format(X) type__format((X)0)


#define declare(T)\
void T##_to_str(void* data, char* buffer, size_t buffer_size) {\
    if (data && buffer)\
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, type_format( T ), *( T *)data);\
}


declare(int16_t)
declare(float)
declare(int)

int main()
{
  int16_t x = 77;
  char buf[10];
  int16_t_to_str(&x, buf, 10);
  puts(buf);
  int v = 888;
  int_to_str(&v, buf, 10);
  puts(buf);
}
```

Правда (я так и не разобрался почему так происходит), пришлось перенести "склеиваемые" части формата внутрь макроса `type__format(T)`.

Если вставить части формата вокруг макроса `type_format` в `snprintf()`, то я получаю ошибки вроде:

```
ttt.c: In function ‘int_to_str’:
ttt.c:10:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘_Generic’
 #define type__format(T) _Generic((T),\
```

У меня

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc --vers; uname -a; cat /etc/issue
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-72-generic #80~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 23:26:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l

avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

--- **Update** ---

Кстати, поскольку вы генерите функции, передавая в макрос тип, а не имя переменной, то  можно просто написать  несколько простых макросов (по одному для каждого типа) для создания форматов (без  `_Generic`). В этом случае можно будет использовать строки прямо в параметрах `snprintf()` формата.

```
#define int16_t_format PRIi16 
#define int32_t_format PRIi32
#define float_format   "g"
#define long_format    "l"
#define int_format     "d"

#define declare(T)\
void T##_to_str(void* data, char* buffer, size_t buffer_size) {\
    if (data && buffer)\
        snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%" T ## _format " ", *( T *)data);\
}
```

Мне кажется, что это простой и очевидный способ.

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка, со склеиванием формата, преследует и меня на всех платформах. Какой-то компилятор выдавал в телефоне выдавал что выражение макроса воспринимается как строковая константа. Возможно объяснения этому таится глубоко в дебрях документации, либо это баг ¯\(o_o)/¯. В любом случае спасибо!

Comment: @YoungSideways, я думаю это следствие того, что Generic обрабатывается уже на этапе компиляции, после всех макроподстановок в препроцессоре. Т.е. если вызвать gcc -E, то в тексте после препроцессора мы видим _Generic(...)

Comment: Проверил, всё работает отлично. Пришлось студию + ко всему обновить. Ещё раз спасибо!